# Delete related data to an object (not updating)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

my problem in short is that when i trying to delete related data to object the system trying to update them and not delete them from the db.

my db schema is

tbl **stations** (id, ....)

tbl **associated_names** (id, name, station_id)

my modules:

```
class Station
has_many :associated_names, :inverse_of => :station
end
class AssociatedName
has_one :station, inverse_of: :associated_names
# belongs_to :station, inverse_of: :associated_names
end
```

now i running the code

```
s = Station.first
s.associated_names.delete_all ==> error
s.associated_name_ids = [1,3] ==> error
```

i know that destroy_all resolve the delete_all, but i looking for updating solution

Thanks!

here is the image of the problematic code:

https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/1011655_10201722818174648_1924981889_n.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the association. "delete" operation sets the foreign key to null default, not deletes the record. Add dependent option to it:

```
class Station
  has_many :associated_names, :inverse_of => :station, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

and execute the code again:

```
s = Station.first
s.associated_names.delete_all
```